# CORS Error while emit from Python 3 socket server to Node js Client

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io, cors

I have set up a Python3 Socket server with reference from:
 https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#server-examples 
The sample code is shown below:

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio
from eventlet.green import subprocess


sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
app = web.Application() 
sio.attach(app)

async def index(request):
with open('index.html') as f:
    return web.Response(text=f.read(), content_type='text/html')

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connect ", sid)

@sio.on('message')
async def message(sid, data):
    ## Some processing that involves subprocess Popen
    ## Using p.communicate to store output of subprocess onto the below variable 'out'
    out = (Json data)
    await sio.emit('reply', out,room=sid)

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)


app.router.add_get('/', index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     web.run_app(app)
```

As the code shows there is a subprocess that calls another python program,does a bit of processing and then stores the output(json) in the 'out' variable which is then emitted onto the client.Now the client code for socket io is written in Node js.When the python server tries to emit this json data to the js client I get an error stating:

       **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**

I tried to find the answers online ,but couldn't get one which would be needed in my situation.What silly mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. First, you need to tell socketio to okay cors.

```
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp', cors_allowed_origins='*')
```

When sio attaches to "app", route is added for socket.io with cors header with "*" - meaning that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header shows up in HTTP reply with "*" for the allowed domain. (You can control the allowed domain if you like.)

So, this is part 1 of all of your problems. There is a part 2. In order to serve "/" or "/index.html", you need to add the same cors header for aiohttp as well. In other word, above single line change only adds the cors header for socket.io, and not for aiohttp.

In order for aiohttp to have cors header, you need to add aiohttp_cors package, import the aiohttp_cors module, and add the cors header to every route, as far as I understand. After you have added all the routes to the router, you do:

```
import aiohttp_cors
cors = aiohttp_cors.setup(app)
# app.router.add_routes(routes) if you have routes
# app.router.add_static("/", rootdir) if you want to serve static, and this has to be absolutely the last route since it's the root. Adding any route after this becomes ignored as '/' matches everthing.
for resource in app.router._resources:
  # Because socket.io already adds cors, if you don't skip socket.io, you get error saying, you've done this already.
  if resource.raw_match("/socket.io/"):
    continue
  cors.add(resource, { '*': aiohttp_cors.ResourceOptions(allow_credentials=True, expose_headers="*", allow_headers="*") })
```

[To make this a little easier, I file a request to aiohttp.](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3866#issuecomment-505324142)